# How to fire tap event on filefield?

Tags: sencha-touch

How can I simulate a tap event on a filefield in Sencha Touch 2?

The background: The filefield is hidden. There is a panel and if user taps on this panel, I want Sencha Touch fire tap event on filefield because I want the filechooser open.

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't the approach I'd take as I wouldn't want an event firing that actually hasn't really fired. Look into focusing the field instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why you need a panel to trigger that event.  Is is to style it nicely.  If so look at [this](http://moduscreate.com/device-camera-access-with-sencha-touch/) article by Crysfel Villa.  He did an amazing job styling the file upload control which prompts the user to browse for a file in desktop mode and take a picture or browse the photo directory when on a mobile device.